# How can I split a string containing n concatenated json string in javascript/nodejs?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Let's say I receive this string from a socket server (which I cannot control):

```
{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.605234Z","x":20,"y":30}}{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.609522Z","x":30,"y":40}}
```

I cannot use JSON.parse since it contains 2 Json string so how can I split into

```
var jsonString1 = {"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.605234Z","x":20,"y":30}}
```

and

```
var jsonString2 = {"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.609522Z","x":30,"y":40}}
```

Note: I may have 1 to n Json strings concatenated in fact

Comment: So you have an array of jsons, to start with. You should then be parsing the array of jsons first, and then each json separately.This is how I do it with Newtonsoft's library for .net.

Comment: I would loop through each character of the string, count the number of '{' and '}' characters. Once the amount of '{' are equal to the amount of '}' you know your first JSON string has ended. Except ofcourse when you start the loop and the amount for both of them is 0

Comment: How about splitting the original string using `split("}{")` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just do:

```js
var data = '{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.605234Z","x":20,"y":30}}{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.609522Z","x":30,"y":40}}';

var sanitized = '[' + data.replace(/}{/g, '},{') + ']';
var res = JSON.parse(sanitized);

console.log(res);
```

However, this will fail if one of the objects contains the `}{` pattern in a string.

Comment: It works but I'd like to print x, y : see https://jsfiddle.net/ys6j038q/

Comment: I ask complementary question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834601/how-to-get-x-y-from-nest-object

Comment: What you get here is an array of objects. If you want to access the `x` property of the second object, you'd have to do `res[1].data.x`.

Answer (score 4):

You can split them by the occurrence of `}` followed directly by `{` (ignoring whitespace).

```
var parts = str.split(/\}\s*\{/g);
for(var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  var part = parts[i].trim();

  if(part[0] !== '{') part = '{' + part;
  if(part[part.length-1] !== '}') part += '}';

  var json = JSON.parse(part);
}
```

Comment: But each json contains nested objects. What if data is : {} ?

Comment: @Veverke Those objects would be split by a comma.

Comment: I was trying something less hard-wired. If this solves the issue, however, it's the answer :)

Comment: @Veverke JSON doesn't allow an unescaped `}{` anywhere outside of strings. [The spec](http://www.json.org/) is very concise, so you can check.

Comment: Why anyway the source of this string does not return an array of jsons ? I would expect a comma separating each distinct js object enclosing the "data" property. If he has control over the source, I would fix this, and make things more intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Just split when `/\}\s*\{/g` and pass a value to fill to the `Array.prototype.reduce` function.

```js
var str = '{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.605234Z","x":20,"y":30}}{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.609522Z","x":30,"y":40}}'

var data = (function(input) {
  let odd = true;
  
  return input.split(/\}\s*\{/g).reduce(function(res, part, i) {
    if(odd) {
      part += "}";
    } else {
      part = "{" + part;
    }
    
    odd = !odd;
    
    res[i] = JSON.parse(part);
    
    return res;
  }, {});
})(str)

console.log("data:", data);
```