# How to get x, y from nested object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an error on line console.log(row.data.x) see https://jsfiddle.net/ys6j038q/

```
  var data = '{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.605234Z","x":20,"y":30}}{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.609522Z","x":30,"y":40}}';

             var sanitized = '[' + data.replace(/}{/g, '},{') + ']';
             var rows = JSON.parse(sanitized);
  console.log(rows);

  for(var row in rows){
    console.log(row.data.x);
    console.log(row.data.y);
  }
```

Comment: you converted it into array. `for in` is for objects

Comment: Don't you know how to ask? I mean post the error message..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) at this context not [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
rows.forEach(function(row){
  console.log(row.data.x);
  console.log(row.data.y);
});
```

`for..in` will give you the enumerable properties from that array object such as `0` and `1`. It will not give the elements in the array.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ys6j038q/1/)

Comment: ok thanks, will mark as good answer

Comment: @Paulpro :) Sure.. would edit it. Non native english speaker is here.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy That's better :) "have to" makes it seem like it is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

It would be `rows[row]` instead

```js
 var data = '{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.605234Z","x":20,"y":30}}{"data":{"time":"2016-08-08T15:13:19.609522Z","x":30,"y":40}}';

 var sanitized = '[' + data.replace(/}{/g, '},{') + ']';
 var rows = JSON.parse(sanitized);
 //console.log(rows);

 for (var row in rows) {
   console.log(rows[row].data.x);
   console.log(rows[row].data.y);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Replace your for loop with-

```
for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){

  console.log(rows[i].data.x);
  console.log(rows[i].data.y);
}
```